# Check if two dirs have the same content

Tags: command-line

I usually name files with some temp names then later rename it as I need.

Now I have two dirs of same name in different locations with same size and number of files, but files are of different names.

So, my question is how to know if  this directory is the same of that directory?

Comment: Are the filenames related in any way between the two directories?

Comment: @Daniel No It's not

Comment: Approx how many files?

Comment: more than 1000 file

Comment: This will require a long script.  Give me some time to answer.

Comment: Take your time, I'm not hurry

Answer (score 5):

As I understood, I found that solution: find only files in both directory, get the md5 hash of each file, sort, and verify if the hashes matches.

In bash, you can get all the files from a dir (including subdirs) using find with `-type f` parameter to get only files, and `-exec md5sum {} \;` to get the MD5 hashes from files. In this way, you must cut off the file names and sort, using `|cut -d\  -f1` and `|sort` to sort the generated hashes. Use this with both dirs, and push the output to a file for each dir:

```
find path/to/dir1 -type f -exec md5sum "{}" \; |cut -d\  -f1 |sort > /tmp/hashes_dir1
find path/to/dir2 -type f -exec md5sum "{}" \; |cut -d\  -f1 |sort > /tmp/hashes_dir2
```

After that, you can just compare the generated files:

```
diff /tmp/hashes_dir1 /tmp/hashes_dir2
```

If the output of the above is empty, both dir's files have the same content. 
If not (for example, there is a duplicated files only in one directory), the output will not be empty.

**Edit:**
Additionally, you can see the correspondent files cutting off the `cut` and the `sort` pipes from the two first commands, pushing the output to the same file, and printing the file with `cat` and a pipe with `sort` to compare:

```
find path/to/dir1 -type f -exec md5sum "{}" \; > /tmp/hashes_dir
find path/to/dir2 -type f -exec md5sum "{}" \; >> /tmp/hashes_dir
cat /tmp/hashes_dir |sort
```

The correspondent files will appear one next to the other.

**Edit2**: To see how it works: http://pastebin.com/dW7LrZkR

Comment: +1 for your effort, to list the identical files would be perfect

Comment: @Maythux then please say that in your question. You only ask how to know if two directories are equal. Do you also need to see the identical files?

Comment: This is a good idea but it assumes no spaces in file names.

Comment: You can cut off the `|cut`, put all in the same archive, and sort, to see the correspondent files.

Comment: @tendon, the solution is to insert quotation marks between {}. I'll edit to improve the answer.

Comment: @DanilodeAndradeMendes no, the quotes are irrelevant, the spaces break the `cut`, not the find. Consider a file called `foo bar.txt`, your `cut` will print `foo` only.

Comment: @DanilodeAndradeMendes It's good, but why not using `diff` itself. This can be done by `diff /path/to/dir1 /path/to/dir2` and it's better using with `-q` option. `-q "report only when files differ"` (`diff -q /path/to/dir1 /path/to/dir2`)

Comment: @terdon no, because just the first space are considered in this command.  If I run: `md5sum dir\ 2/a\ long\ name\ for\ a\ subdir/The\ Foo`, the result will be: `eb4585ad9fe0426781ed7c49252f8225  dir 2/a long name for a subdir/The Foo`. The first field will be necessarily the hash. After that, doesn't matter if the file name have none, one, or fifty spaces, all of them, including the file name, will be discarded.

Take a look in Edit2 to see how it works.

Comment: @KasiyA, you can take a look too.